# Can't SSH into AWS instance ubuntu and hosted sites not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC-2 instance with running RESTapi and a single page web site. `SSH` to it and doing builds worked fine. But suddenly I am not able to login to the instance using `SSH`. When putting my SSH command it took a very long time and gives me

> Connection closed by MY_IP port 22

- I created a new EC-2 instance from the same account with the same key
  file and I am able to login into that. So I can assume it's not
  something with the key file.
- This should not be the wrong user name. Because previously I use the same user name.
- I reboot my instance and the result is the same.

And also I tried to access the RESTapi and the website. Those also not working. So this is not just a login issue, but something related to that instance.

How do I fix this problem?

Any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you validated the IP address in the console before retrying? If you have no elastic IP its IP will change every time you reboot

Comment: I think IP is fine.

Comment: Have you checked any instance metrics, such as CPU utilizatin? Maybe you run out of CPU/ram/disk ?